Evaluating the difference of weighted binomial coefficients
I encountered the following type of sum:
$$
\begin{align}
\left[
\sum_{k=1}^{t}\binom{k+i-2}{i-1}\binom{t-k+l_1-i}{l_1-i}\sum_{s=k}^{t}\binom{t-s+l_2-j+1}{l_2-j+1}\binom{s+j-3}{j-2}
\right] \tag{1} \\
\left[
\sum_{k=1}^{t}\binom{k+i-2}{i-1}\binom{t-k+l_1-i+1}{l_1-i}\binom{k+j-3}{j-1}\binom{t-k+l_2-j+2}{l_2-j+1}
\right] \tag{2} \\
\left[
\sum_{k=1}^{t}\binom{k+i-2}{i-1}\binom{t-k+l_1-i}{l_1-i}\sum_{s=k}^{t}\binom{t-s+l_2-j+2}{l_2-j+1}\binom{s+j-3}{j-2}
\right] \tag {3} \\
\left[
\sum_{k=1}^{t}\binom{k+i-2}{i-1}\binom{t-k+l_1-i}{l_1-i}\binom{k+j-3}{j-1}\binom{t-k+l_2-j+1}{l_2-j+1}
\right] \tag {4}
\end{align}
$$
$$(1)\times(2)-(3)\times(4)\geq 0$$
when I was playing around with some poset order polynomial inequalities. Here, $1\leq i\leq l_1$ and $1\leq j\leq l_2$, and both of them are fixed. I would like to prove that difference is always non-negative regardless of $i, j, t$.
As you can see many of the terms are quite similar, but if you group them together is becomes a weighted sum of products of binomial coefficients, which I have no idea how to deal with...
I'm a beginner in math researches and I have so little background knowledge in asymptotic or finite differences that were used to solve similar questions posted on MO. Please let me know if there's any systematic solutions. Many thanks!
Edit 1: I have rewrote my expression in a more readable format. And I wrote a python program to enumerate over some small values of $t, l_1, l_2, i, j$ and they are all non-negative.

@SamHopkins I have edited my expression so it's more readable. My conjecture is that the expression is nonnegative for all valid parameters. If you have any suggestions on readings or tools that deal with similar problems, that would be very helpful.
